# Is my MySQL library wrapper neat? How can I do better?

Tags: c, mysql

I'm moderately new to programming in C and I'm not sure about programming practices with code; suddenly I have had fears that my code is messy and disorganized. I can read it when I come back a month later yet I'm still nervous if I'm doing anything that's considered taboo.

This isn't all the code that I've done with this project, I think my other code is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "errh.h"
#include "mysqlerr.h"

void FIRST_TIME_HANDLER(MYSQL *conn) 
{
    printw("[+] Doing initialization checks...\n"); 
    SEND_MYSQL_QUERY(conn, "create table IF NOT EXISTS user_2(username varchar(25) not null, passwd varchar(25) not null)");
    printw("[+] Handler has checked tables.\n"); 
    refresh();
}

void INThandler(int sig)
{
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
    printw("Closing server...\n");
    refresh();
    sleep(5);
    endwin();
    exit(0);
}

MYSQL_INFO *CONNECTION_INIT()
{
    MYSQL_INFO *info = malloc(sizeof(*info));
    info->IP = "IPADDRGOHERE"; info->user = "Hello"; 
    info->pass = "World"; info->DB = "DBGOHERE";
    return info;
}

int EXIT_SERVER(MYSQL *connection)
{
    mysql_close(connection);
    printw("MySQL session has now closed.\n"); 
    refresh();
    return KILL_SIGNAL;
}

MYSQL *MYSQL_CONNECT_DB(MYSQL_INFO *info)
{
    MYSQL *connection;
    const char *server = info->IP; 
    const char *user = info->user;
    const char *password = info->pass;
    const char *database = info->DB;

    connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    if(!mysql_real_connect(connection, server, user, password, database, 0, 
        NULL, 0))
    {
        //printw("[-] Error: %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
        MYSQL *f = KILL_SIGNAL;
        refresh();
        return f;
    }

    printw("[+] Connected to MySQL server.\n");
    FIRST_TIME_HANDLER(connection);
    return connection;
}

void SEND_MYSQL_QUERY(MYSQL *conn, const char *query)
{
    refresh();
    if(mysql_query(conn, query))
    {
        ERROR err;
        throw_error_init(err, 0, 1, NONFATAL, "MySQL QUERY ERROR", 
            "ERROR IN THE PROCESS OF QUERY.", MySQL_query_error);
    }
    else 
    {
        printw("Query sent.\n");
    }
}

int init_connection() 
{
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_INFO *info = CONNECTION_INIT();

    if((conn = MYSQL_CONNECT_DB(info)) == (MYSQL *) 0)
    {
        ERROR err;
        throw_error_init(err, 1, 1, FATAL, "INIT CONNECTION ERROR", 
            "Failed to connect to server.", MySQL_init_failure);
    } 
    else {   
        int key;
        nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);

        signal(SIGINT, INThandler);

        while(1)
        {
            if((key = getch()) == ERR)
            {
                if(mysql_ping(conn) == 1)
                { 
                    printw("Error!\n");
                    refresh(); 
                    return 1;
                } 
            } 
            else 
            {
                if(key == EOF) break;
            }
        }

        free(info);
        EXIT_SERVER(conn);
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you also include the corresponding header file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally avoid `while(1)` loops. Maybe rewrite that piece of code like this:

```
    while((key = getch()) != EOF)
    {
        if(key == ERR && mysql_ping(conn) == 1)
        { 
            printw("Error!\n");
            refresh(); 
            return 1;
        } 
    }
```

`while(1)` is conceptually "go on and on forever", but this is not your case. This way you don't even need to call a `break`.

Comment: Wow it looks a lot neater already!

Answer (score 4):

1. In C the naming conventions typically are `lower_case_with_underscore` for function names and types (although for types some people also use `PascalCase`). `UPPERCASE` is only really used for macro definitions.
2. In `CONNECTION_INIT` you have a bunch of hard-coded settings. These should come from a config file or via command line arguments.
3. In `init_connection` you write:

   ```
   if((conn = MYSQL_CONNECT_DB(info)) == (MYSQL *) 0)
   ```

   - There is no reason to cast in order to compare it to `NULL`, simply `== NULL` works and is more idiomatic.
   - There is no reason to do the assignment and compare in one statement. Splitting it up makes the if statement less crammed:

     ```
     conn = MYSQL_CONNECT_DB(info);
     if (conn == NULL)
     {
         ...
     ```
4. I assume `printw` is some kind of way to print debug/info/tracing messages. If so then this is not a good name for the function. Better would `log_info` or similar (depending on the exact purpose).
5. There is this magic `refresh` method called everywhere but it doesn't seem to follow any particular pattern. Seems suspicious to me.

Comment: Just got home. printw and refresh are a part of the ncurses library. Ignore those. Thanks for the advice, I'll fix those up.

Answer (score 4):

All of what @ChrisWue is saying in his answer, plus:

- Avoid putting multiple statements on a single line (your `CONNECTION_INIT` method)
- To increase readability, decrease your indent level : in your `SEND_MYSQL_QUERY` and `init_connection` methods, just add a `return` statement to your error management "ifs", and get rid of the `else`, as you do in your `MYSQL_CONNECT_DB`
- I don't see the `ERROR err` variable utility, as it seems only to be used inside the `throw_error_init` method
- In your `MYSQL_CONNECT_DB`, you return a `KILL_SIGNAL` constant if something went wrong, but when you call this method, you test for a `(MYSQL *) 0` value (or `NULL` as @ChrisWue suggested). Be coherent: either return a NULL value if something goes wrong, or test for a `KILL_SIGNAL` constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the ERROR err variable is needed for another function. Already the code is looking a lot nicer. Thank you!